# looking for simple 3d games made with Qt

Tags: qt

Hi 
i need to make simple education games in 3d for that i need GUI and editor like function 
this is no problem . but the openGL stuff i need to learn by example.
do you know places where i see example of simple 3d games made with Qt ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. You don't build games with Qt as such. If you need help on the OpenGL part, then look for OpenGL games. And accept answers to previous questions.

Comment: @The Communist Duck: and why not? I wouldn't choose Qt either to make a game but this is possible. There is 3D rendering api (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/painting-3d.html) and it was even asked Qt users if they wanted more tools to make games with Qt (http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/09/16/improved-support-for-writing-games-using-qt/), finally you can find a "how to write game with QML" here: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/08/12/a-guide-to-writing-games-with-qml/ and a game development section on the nokia forum: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewforum/17/

Comment: Hm,I didn't see that. Either way, the OP is saying the 'openGL stuff' so I assume they are using the the GUI bit which is no problem for them..therefore, their problem is with OpenGL not Qt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know any 3D game made with Qt, but here are some useful links about creating 3D scenes and animations using the Qt 3D rendering api (QtGL is based upon OpenGL) or about game creation with Qt.

First, here is a very interesting step by step tutorial/demo to present QML and 3D. Which I think could be very helpful for you, because all you need (for the 3D part) is in there:

- http://blog.qt.digia.com/2010/08/10/qml3d-demo/

Next one is about using QML for creating simple game (non 3D), but it can be interesting even if you want to create a 3D game, and particularly for the "Implementing the game logic" part:

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick2-qml-advtutorial.html
- http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/08/12/a-guide-to-writing-games-with-qml/ (article related to the tutorial)

Finally you can search read the forum section dedicated to games on the Qt Project's forum, and the QTGL documentation:

- http://qt-project.org/forums/viewforum/17/
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/painting-3d.html
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/painting-3d.html

Answer (score 1):

[simple shooter Qt project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qute3d/)